# Hugo: how to create a link to page in a shortcode?

Tags: hugo, hugo-shortcode

In a shortcode I want to create a link to an hugo page, how can I do this ?

I tried

```
{{< ref "page_name" >}}
```

but I get an error `parse failed unexpected "<" in command` .

I could use for example `<a href="https:/www.example.com/test/">Test</a>` but this is tied to the domain where the site is hosted, I want to be able to use it without this constraint.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how I can do this, this link was helpful:

https://github.com/parsiya/Hugo-Shortcodes/blob/master/shortcodes/xref.html

so in shortcode I used:

```
{{ $path := .Get "path" }}
{{ $path := trim $path "/" }}
<!-- now pass it to the relref function -->
{{ $relreflink := relref . $path }}

<a href="{{ $relreflink }}" title="Some title" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Some text</a>
```

In markdown code then I can use:

`{{< my-shortcode path="/my_page" >}}`

It seems to work.

Comment: How is this different than using standard markdown `[]()` , just more complex? IS their some specific thing it handes for you?

Comment: From what I know shortcodes are HTML templates, you cannot use markdown on shortcodes. This is just an example the shortcode doesn't create just a link, there was other things. So I cannot simply use `[]()` for my task

Comment: Thanks for your answer res1. So a shortcode is used within a markdown page right? So _index.md - somewhere in their you plop the shortcode. 
Okay - fine. 
So, because you want to "generally" keep markdown, markdown - and if all you are doing is adding some blaa blaa to the links, then you use a Render hook - keeping your markdown markdown and adding some processing in the backend. That's kind of the point I wanted to make clear - the above code you state as a hdnling isn't a "best practice" Nor a "worst practice" but possibly a "blind practice".

Comment: Interesting the Render hook feature.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is `relref`

From [the documentation](https://gohugo.io/content-management/cross-references/#use-ref-and-relref):

```
{{< relref "document" >}}
{{< relref "document.md" >}}
{{< relref "#anchor" >}}
{{< relref "/blog/my-post.md" >}}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work, same error but I found a way. I will answer my own question.

Answer (score -1):

`[]()` <- Hugo pages are markdown - this is the way to create a link with markdown.

So:

```
[Test](/test/)
```

If you want to specifically use a shortcode, the other answer of various shortcodes works - but - the above gives you *describe* that you want.